# How to conditionally avoid 'nil can't be coerced into Integer' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using the code below, I'm getting a 'nil can't be coerced into Integer' error in Rails.

In my view:

```
<%= account_totals %>
```

In a view helper:

```
def account_totals
  if @user.accounts.any?
    account_total = 0
    @user.accounts.each do |account|
      account_total += account.amount
    end
    account_total
  end
end
```

It's happening because the user has no accounts associated with them, so 'account.percent' is nil. However, I'm first checking to see if the user has any accounts, so this code should not be running if they don't have any accounts.

What's the right way to sum up the total amounts from a user's accounts?

Comment: Your `account_totals` can simply be `@user.accounts.sum(:amount)`, assuming that `amount` is a column in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because some of the `account` records have `nil` amount, you can convert them to `integer` by calling `to_i` or to float by `to_f`, here `account.amount` is returning nil somewhere, do this

```
account_total += account.amount.to_i
```

It will resolve the error. But since `amount` is a numeric column, you should better set the default value as 0 in migrations at DB level.

or, use `sum`

```
account_total = @user.accounts.sum(:amount)
```

It avoids `nil` values and runs a SQL `sum`

Answer (score 1):

```
def account_totals
  @user.accounts.map(&:amount).compact.sum
end
```

If there are no accounts, `@user.accounts` will be an empty collection. Empty collections still respond to all of the same methods as populated ones, so the `map` and `sum` call will work - they will just be empty.

`nil`s can be removed from a collection with `.compact`

To be honest, your question is kind of confused; you refer to `account.percent` which is not in your code snippet; and if the `accounts` collection is empty then the `+=` will NOT run. Since you are getting the coercion error we have to assume that this code IS running, and `account.amount` is `nil`. Consider defaulting `amount` to `0` in the Account model if that makes sense. Otherwise, use `compact` to filter `nil`s out of arrays like I say above. IF you DO default `amount` to `0`, you can use the snippet in @AbM 's comment for maximum clarity and minimalism.

Comment: If you have a large number of records this will explode. It's better to let your database do the work on this one.

Comment: Great point @JoshBrody , definitely important to keep in mind. When it comes to stack overflow and I don't have lots of context I prefer to code for brevity and recommend that performance bottlenecks are analyzed once they are a problem - in particular I wasn't certain that accounts were in the database here. But senior engineers that know their data models can preempt those performance problems with your answer

Answer (score 1):

Just do it on the database:

```
@users = User.select('users.*', 'SUM(accounts.amount) AS account_totals')
             .left_joins(:accounts)
             .group(:id)
```

Most dbs will coalesce null values into 0 when using SUM.

If you are just fetching a single user and two queries is ok you can use  [`ActiveRecord::Calcations#sum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum).

```
@user = User.find(1)
account_totals = @user.accounts.sum(:amount)
```

Don't do this while looping through a collection of users though as it creates a n+1 query issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
def account_totals
    # Initalizing total to 0
    account_total = 0
  if @user.accounts.any?
    @user.accounts.each do |account|
      account_total += account.amount
    end
  end
  #Allways return total, that wil be 0 or other value
 account_total
end
```

In you code, if the user don't has accounts nil is returned